# Is it possible to put delay between tasks or conditional loop

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

Is it possible to either loop or delay between running tasks in either build or release pipelines? I deploy containers as part of those pipelines and they take time to spin up and be available for webtests, so I can not run webtest immediately following Release task. What can be a solution to this requirements inside TFS or VSTS?

Comment: Are you using the Docker extension or are you running home-grown scripts to do this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker

Comment: Docker built-in task by Microsoft. This still does not solve the issue since after the service deployment and build I need to check if it's running properly and issue HTTP request to it. It takes a minute to spin up and initialize a container and I need to know how to pause or run in a loop test

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Put an in-line PowerShell task in place that runs `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` or however long you want to wait.

Or better yet, write your own script that polls your containers for availability.

Comment: This solution functionally works, and is probably the best choice if the delay is a few seconds, but for any longer delay (minutes+), one thing to keep in mind is that this keeps an agent from your pool that is not doing anything useful. For such longer delays, the agentless job/phase approach (in smoksnes' answer) is probably a better use of the pool resources, even if the resumption of the pipeline means redownloading sources/artifacts/etc.

Answer (score 18):

You can add an [Agentless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks) phase and put a [Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delay?view=azure-devops)-task in it. Then  your build will be delayed X minutes. Then you may continue your pipeline with an `agent phase`. Just make sure to configure `Run this phase` or set a dependency between the phases. This works in TFS and Azure Devops Server.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As shown for release tasks by [smoksnes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58621122/13404308), the [Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delay-v1?view=azure-pipelines) *agentless* task can also be used in Azure DevOps YAML (build) pipelines. Here is an example:

```yaml
pool: server

steps:
  - task: Delay@1
    inputs:
      delayForMinutes: '5'
```

Note that the `pool: server` is the key here. It makes this task run without the need of an agent. ADO offers a few of these [agentless tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks), manual validation for example may be useful if the delay you need isn't consistent.